# Node.js and Server Sent Events

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I had a problem with **SSE** as soon as I deployed my app on **Heroku**.

In the logs for the SSE there was this error:

```
Error: 500 RangeError: msecs must be a non-negative finite number
GET /live/redis 500 102.270 ms - -
```

In my route controller for `/live/redis` the first line was:

```
// let request last as long as possible
req.socket.setTimeout(Infinite);
```

I just copied it following a guide on the web but it was causing that error. So I changed it with this:

```
// let request last as long as possible
req.socket.setTimeout(0x7FFFFFFF);
```

Now it is working as expected but my question is: is it the correct way to solve this issue? There is a better parameter to pass in the `setTimeout` to be like `Infinite`?

Comment: IMHO some sensible timeout would be... well, more sensible.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I'm new working with SSE...

Comment: For example if the client is a web browser, settting a longer a timeout than the browser is totally unneccesary.

Comment: Yes, it is a browser. Which timeout should be better to insert to let it work properly? Considering that it receive many messages from the API during the day...

Comment: `0x7FFFFFFF` is approximately 24 days.

Comment: One day should then be enough? Basically these are dashboards update...

Answer (score -1):

May be you could try Number.MAX_VALUE instead, It works for me.